# How can I set a color when using Range.BorderAround?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automate the creation of a data table. I found a border color that I want to have for the created table. `.Color = 15849925` and\or `.ColorIndex = 24`.

But when I do `MyRange.BorderAround xlContinuous, xlThin, 24` the color that appears on the sheet is not the same. It's purplish instead of pale blue. `BorderAround` also accepts `Color` instead of `ColorIndex`, but when I try `MyRange.BorderAround xlContinuous, xlThin, , 15849925` it comes out black (no color).

I also tried using the `Color` argument while `ColorIndex` was set to `xlColorIndexAutomatic` or `xlColorIndexNone`. No difference, it still appears black.

The obvious workaround would be to set the borders without color and then color them each one by one afterward. But I am really wondering what I've done wrong with `BorderAround`. **How can I set the color when using Range.BorderAround?**

Excel 2007 12.0.4518.1014

Comment: "*[You can](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.borderaround?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144252)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue#remarks) specify either LineStyle or Weight, but not both*".

Comment: Good catch! unfortunately, `MyRange.BorderAround , xlThin, , 15849925` is still not giving me any color. Am I missing something else?

Comment: That is a very pale blueish color that is very hard to distinguish from the Excel's default cell divider color.

Comment: `Range("A1:D4").BorderAround Color:=15849925, Weight:=xlThick` works for me

Comment: @GSerg Yes! When the cells have a fill color, the default line disappears, and I wanted to add a pale line back onto those filled cells. Slightly blue instead of grey.

Comment: Time to verify that `MyRange` contains what you think it contains then.

Comment: @TimWilliams That works, but its purple?? Question answered (kind of). Its so strange. When using `Range.Borders.Color = 15849925` the color becomes pale blue, but `BorderAround` creates purple... Honestly, I'm okay throwing in the towel on that one. I can just reset the color after creating the borders.

Comment: On my system 15849925 is a pale blue (for both fill/border), not purple.